# How to create multipart upload to s3 (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

is there any gem/ plugin or any refference to create multipart upload to s3 in Ruby on Rails?

ref : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html

I wish to create upload very large file and need to seperate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this plugin for uploading files directly to the amazon s3. I am going to use it in my the current project.

[Carrierwave Direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct)

Comment: sorry wrong reference, so this is the correct one http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html